# Is it haram to keep a dog outside the house?

Tags: halal-haram, dogs

I have a dog and I live in a ten story building. My dog lives in the basement. We have a few foreigners in our building who like to take the dog home. My dog stays in the ground floor. There is no reason why I keep it. I touch it but I always wash my hands. and I always take care of it. My dog has never visited my home though.

Is it a sin to keep my dog with me?

Comment: No as long as you dont bring to house :)

Answer (score 2):

### It depends:

There are two main views on dogs in Islam. One view, and the most common one is the Shafi'i madhab, which considers dogs to be najis (ritually unclean) while the Maliki madhab differs, and considers dogs to be pure.<sup>1</sup>

So with that, we understand that if you are of the Maliki madhab it is viewed as halal to own a dog.<sup>3</sup> (Keeping it in your home if a different story.) The Shafi'i madhab on the other hand, prohibits ownership of dogs, except for hunting, herding, farming, and or guarding.

As for keeping your dog in your own home, for Shafi'i madhab adherents, it is viewed as strictly haram (understood on a textual basis), while for Maliki madhab adherents view it is makrooh only.<sup>2</sup> Maliki madhab adherents draw this conclusion from hadith reference 4, they see it as a show of indication that it is not haram, just makrooh.

---

#### References:

<sup>1:</sup>Ahmad Ibn Muhammad al-Dardir, al-Sharh al-Saghir ‘ala Aqrab al-Masalik

<sup>2:</sup>Whoever would keep a dog for other than hunting, herding or farming will lose a great reward every day. - Bukhari

<sup>3:</sup>Dalil Falihin ala Riyad al-Salihin; Hashiya `Adawi ala Sharh Kifaya al-Talib al-Rabbani

<sup>4:</sup>The angels (of blessings) do not enter homes with statues, drawn pictures of live beings or dogs. - Bukhari/Abu Dawood

Answer (score -1):

Dog's are not Haram.... I'm a mufti and I have dogs, cats, and hamsters, dog's are just mukrooh (disliked) but the thing is if you have one teach it not to lick you or anything, dogs itself are clean, but the saliva and urine is not cause it carries E. Coil, so there's nothing negative about dog's cause cats carry more bacteria and disease's more than dog's do, and the Hadith did lie about Muhammad and jibreel hating or not allowing dogs especially black ones, this is all a myth, I'm not surprised cause the story is about 'huba alqut" which means love of the kitten

Comment: Claims should be supported by evidence.

Answer (score -5):

It is haram because it brings jinn.  But you can keep it in your backyard and everything is good, as long as you take a shower after you touch it.

But in your house is strictly bad.

Comment: Dog's aren't devils...so how can you make the assumption that they bring jinns. Please use evidence